# Как реализовать перенос текста в EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Когда пишу текст, все пишется в одну строку. Как только содержимое становится больше, чем EditText, то текст уходит дальше.
Как сделать так, чтобы текст сам автоматически переносился на новую строку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Достаточно добавить аттрибут `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233626/allow-multi-line-in-edittext-view-in-android